# Django template : sorting by value of __str__

Tags: django

I am using django 3 and I have surcharged the **str** function for my model :

```
class SubSubCategory(models.Model):
    subCategory         = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name                = models.CharField("Nom du sous sous category"         , max_length=200, )
    description         = models.CharField("Description du sous sous category" , max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        description_locale  = self.name + " : " + self.description if self.description else self.name
        hierarchie          = [str(x) for x in [self.subCategory.category, self.subCategory, description_locale]]
        description_totale  = " > ".join(hierarchie)
        return description_totale
```

How could I ask my template to order my list according to this **str** representation ?

I would like to do something like :

```
{% for SubSubcategory in object_list|dictsort:'str' %}
```

but it obviously doesn't work, as "str" is nothing. How do I call the string representation of an object in a template ? to pass it as an ordering order ?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution could be to just present it as a property as well:

```
class SubSubCategory(models.Model):
    # …

    @property
    def catstr(self):
        return str(self)

    def __str__(self):
        # …
```

Then you can sort on that property:

```
{% for SubSubcategory in object_list|dictsort:'catstr' %}
    …
{% endfor %}
```

That being said, I'm not sure that sorting in the template is a good idea. A template should only be concerned with *rendering logic*, not *template logic*.

Answer (score 0):

Make another field in model named other than 'str' and then write same logic written in **str** method into save() method of django model this way you can make a new field changes as soon as model is created

Comment: I can't as the str representation may change according to upper categories values...

Comment: yes its correct but in these types of cases i prefer adding addtional methods in models instead of writing logic in built in functions so try there mate

Answer (score 0):

I would rather pass the ***sorted object to the template*** from the view as,

```
class SomeView(...):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["object_list"] = sorted(context["object_list"], key=lambda sub_cat: sub_cat.__str__())
        return context
```

Reference: [**`sorted(...)`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted)